# How do I delete emails that have been lost from exchange?

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, exchange, outlook

There is a bit of a story about this one:

I had exchange 2003 installed on windows server 2003, the hard drive that stored its emails had bad blocks and needed to be replace. As you know exchange data is stored in two files .edb and .stm, I was able to copy the edb file to a new hard drive fine but not the stm file. I then performed a recreation of the stm file using eseutil.

Exchange is now working fine and most emails have been preserved, how ever some emails in outlook are showing as having date, from, to, subject but the body of the email has been lost. I want to be able to delete these emails I get the message this email could not be deleted, it was either moved or deleted or access was denied.

Ideally I want to delete the emails I choose as the subject and from information is useful but if that is not possible something that clears out all these emails from exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You might try exporting the affected mailboxes to .PST, deleting the mailbox and then re-importing the .PST into the new/replacement mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I was hoping for a less tedious solution but it at least this way works.

Comment: There was a migration tool, back in the 5.x/pre-5.x days, which would "automate" the pst-migration process for multiple mailboxes.